# Error on FileCopy when there are white spaces in path and name

Tags: c#

I've seen some questions regarding this topic, but none of them solved the problem completely.

I want to copy some files, overwriting if the name already exists. The function File.Copy(source, destination,true) **works perfectly if the destination file does not exists**, and also if the original file has **no withespaces in its path**.

BUT when there are whitespaces, I get an "Access denied" error. I have permissions in both paths, and the rest of the files are correctly overwritten.

Tried with "@" literal with no luck, also quoting both paths (got an ArgumentException in this case).

Here is my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalPaths = pathList.Count;
        int totalCorrectPaths = 0;
        string currentFile = "";
        string failedFiles = "";
        string destination = "";
        bool errors=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPaths; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt16((100.0 * i) / totalPaths);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
            //currentFile = (String) listBox1.SelectedValue;
            currentFile = pathList.ElementAt(i);
            try
            {
                destination=Path.Combine(textBox2.Text,Path.GetFileName(currentFile));
                File.Copy(currentFile,destination, true);
                totalCorrectPaths++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\nCopiando el archivo:\n" + currentFile, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                errors = true;
                failedFiles+="\n"+ex.Message+" "+currentFile;
            }
        }
        if (errors)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(totalCorrectPaths +" canciones se han copiado correctamente"+"\nErrores al copiar los siguientes archivos:\n" + failedFiles, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show(totalCorrectPaths +" canciones se han copiado correctamente", "Finalizado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Any hint will be very appreciated.

UPDATE 3: Definitely not a permission issue on source folder, as rest of the files got succesfully copied. Running as admin did not improve it.

Maybe you are right and I am pointing in the wrong direction, but I can't figure what's wrong. Here is an image with some of the names that throw errors (with my current test they are 20 out of 820 files). Sorry about screenshot in spanish, each line is composed of "destination" "UnauthorizedAccessException.Message" "source".

Screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGp6.png

UPDATE 4: As some of you pointed, i was wrong, as the example suggested by @sstan works, still can't figure what do the failing files have in common

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\test this\hello 1.txt");
        string destination = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\test this\hello 2.txt");
        File.Copy(source, destination, true);
    }
```

**UPDATE 5: The code above works, the following one reproduces the fail** (first execution works, 2nd and following fail due to the file already present)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\test this\01 Test.mp3");
        string destination = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\test this\01 Test copy.mp3");
        File.Copy(source, destination, true);
    }
```

Comment: sometimes paths have odd ways of represent spaces and whitespace? For example, in a directory in a terminal you have to escape it. Not an elegant solution, but it might help

Comment: Try putting double quotes `"` around `currentFile` and `destination` before calling `File.Copy()`. `Path.Combine()` makes sure slashes, etc. are correct but I do not think it will quote long filenames or paths containing whitespace.

Comment: @lgb: I think you are making assumptions about what the cause of the error is, and are leading us in the wrong direction.  Can you please add traces of the filenames in the code, and then post back the names of the source and target filepaths + the exact error message and stacktrace that you get.

Comment: Or better yet, do what I did: create yourself a very simple console application that only does something like the following: `File.Copy(@"C:\test this\hello.txt", @"C:\test this\target.txt", true);`.  Then test that, and you'll see like me, that it works perfectly.  Then you'll see that the problem has nothing to do with the spaces. Hopefully this will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @sstan I just tested this myself in a simple application and it does indeed work without quotes.

Comment: I agree with @sstan. I do not think that's an issue with white spaces. Try creating 2 new files with some white spaces that nobody would possibly use at the same time in a different directory such as C:\MyDirectory_Src\  (make sure it's NOT C:\users\ ) and copying it to C:\MyDirectory_Dest\.

Comment: Since the access denied error message is on the path (not the file) check your permissions on the destination directory.

Comment: Is it an `.mp3` specific problem?  Are you able to copy any mp3 files successfully?  Could it be related to some form of virus scanner that locks the mp3 files as you are trying to copy them?  If you do have an anti-virus of some sort, try to disable it while you perform the copy, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: An internationalization problem?  Do the languages on your development machine/target machine match, and where was the original/target file created?

Comment: @sstan many thanks for your suggestion, thanks to it i identified the problem.
I copied one of the problematic mp3 files, and got the problem even when i removed whitespaces.
Then i tried with an empty file renamed to mp3, and it worked.
You were right, it had nothing to do with spaces. The files were marked as read only. Newbie mistake on my part :(

Comment: @Igb: Do you mind posting an answer explaining what the problem/solution was exactly.  It may help someone else in the future.

Comment: @sstan i just edited the previous comment with that info. I was planning to add it in first place, but sent comment too fast by mistake. Should i add it as a response?

Comment: @lgb: Yes, that would be good I think. It will give us closure :).  Just add an answer and accept it yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem: the readonly attribute.

Most of the comments were right, finally it wasn't related to whitespaces despite i pointed to it seeing the errors, it was just a coincidence with some of the first items of the list.

As I stated in the comments, found the problem thanks to ssatan suggestion about the problem being format related. I copied some of the faulty files to other folder, and got failed copys despite removing all the whitespaces. After that i made an empty mp3 file with the same name as the original, it worked like a charm.

Seems obvious now, the copied file carries the readonly attribute with him. It's ignored if i copy it manually, but the File.Copy() function checks it and throws an UnauthorizedAccessException (as it should).